Characterizing incomplete beta function solving given condition
(editing with simplified problem)
I'd like to solve for an $\alpha, \beta$ corresponding to a Beta distribution that satisfies this condition...
$$
\int_0^x a^{\alpha-1}(1-a)^{\beta-1} da = \left(\omega \left(\int_0^x a^{\alpha}(1-a)^{\beta-1} da\right)^{\rho} + (1-\omega) \left(\int_0^x (a^{\alpha-1}(1-a)^{\beta} da\right)^{\rho}\right)^{\frac{1}{\rho}}
$$
Which corresponds to (raising both sides to $\rho$)...
$$
B(x; \alpha, \beta)^\rho = \omega B(x; \alpha+1, \beta)^\rho + (1-\omega) B(x; \alpha, \beta+1)^\rho
$$
Where $B(x; \alpha, \beta)$ is an incomplete beta function. Since that can't be directly computed, I know I can't directly solve for an analytic solution, but I was hoping to characterize how the solution changes with $\omega$.
Here are the constraints on my exogenous parameters...
$$
x \in [0,1], \rho \in (-\infty, 1), \omega \in [0,1]
$$

Are you looking for solutions over the entire set of exogenous parameters, or would it be helpful to look at solutions for particular fixed values of $x, \rho, \omega$?

I'm not confident the edge cases that are obvious ($\rho = 0/1$, $\omega = 0/1$, offer guidance for the interior. I know that for $\rho=0$ you can recover a analytic form for the PDF that's double Pareto; see Houthakker 1955). Looking at the problem again, I think I need to restrict further, i.e. either have a symmetric Beta function or change to a joint distribution PDF like double Pareto.

You're right! I think I've corrected now. Also I think it doesn't change my solution for the x=1 case below. Thank you!

I've made progress on a simplified version of this problem, so thought I'd post it. Restrict $x=1$; now the problem is...
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^1 a^{\alpha-1} (1-a)^{\beta-1} da = \left(\omega \left(\int_0^1 a^{\alpha}(1-a)^{\beta-1} da\right)^{\rho} + (1-\omega) \left(\int_0^1 a^{\alpha-1}(1-a)^{\beta} da\right)^{\rho}\right)^{\frac{1}{\rho}} 
\end{aligned}
$$
Observe that this is an equation relating three different (complete! not incomplete) beta functions...
$$
B(\alpha, \beta) = \left(\omega B(\alpha+1, \beta)^\rho + (1-\omega) B(\alpha, \beta+1)^\rho\right)^{\frac{1}{\rho}}
$$
Rewrite our beta functions in terms of gamma functions...
$$
\begin{aligned}
B(\alpha, \beta) = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)} = \left(\omega \frac{\Gamma(\alpha+1)\Gamma(\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta+1)}^\rho + (1-\omega) \frac{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta+1)}{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta+1)}^\rho\right)^{\frac{1}{\rho}} 
\end{aligned}
$$
Now leverage that $\Gamma(x+1) = x\Gamma(x)$...
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)} = \left(\omega \frac{\alpha \Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)}{(\alpha+\beta)\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}^\rho + (1-\omega) \frac{\beta \Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)}{(\alpha+\beta) \Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}^\rho\right)^{\frac{1}{\rho}} \\
1 = \left(\omega \left(\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta}\right)^\rho + (1-\omega) \left(\frac{\beta}{\alpha+\beta}\right)^\rho\right)^{\frac{1}{\rho}}
\end{aligned}
$$
Set $t = \frac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta}$, and observe $1-t = \frac{\beta}{\alpha+\beta}$...
$$
\begin{aligned}
1 = \left(\omega t^\rho + (1-\omega)(1-t)^\rho\right)^{\frac{1}{\rho}} \\
1 = \omega t^\rho + (1-\omega)(1-t)^\rho \\
\end{aligned}
$$
This equation characterizes $t$; it's nonlinear though, so we can't solve for a simple analytic formula. And when I start solving numerically, I don't always get answers

$(p,t)\mapsto wt^p+(1-w)(1-t)^p$ for fixed $t$ is decreasing in $p$ and reaches $1$ only for $p=0.$ As a consequence if $p\neq 0$ the number  $wt^p+(1-w)(1-t)^p$  is always different of 1.
